# Tomcat is not reading .properties file

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I am developing a struts2 application over Eclipse. I have a `.properties` file which changes the `struts.date.format` properly. Deploying the application in `localhost` using Eclipse tools works fine and the dateformat is showed correctly.

But when I deploy the `.war` on the production Tomcat server, the transformation doesn't work and dates are being shown as if no properties were specified. The file is being exported into the `.war`, but it's simply not reading it.

I thought that maybe the application context is not being cleaned when redeploying, but I deleted the whole application directory and still nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show the code how do you read the properties.

Comment: @RomanC Just `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="prop" />` in `struts.xml` file, and having a `prop.properties` file. As I said, over `localhost` is working, but not when deploying the exact same project in another server.

Comment: then you have missed the file there.

Comment: @RomanC No, Eclipse is creating the `.war` correctly and the file is in there.

Comment: What does it mean the transformation doesn't work? Could you see the messages text?

Comment: In `localhost` I am seeing dates over .jsp the way I want: `06/06/2013`. In the production server, I am seeing `6-jun-2013 0:00:00`, so I think is ignoring the properties file, despite it is being deployed.

Comment: You say you have cleaned the application, but you did it partially and not complete. Also you need to clean `work` and `temp` dirs clean rebuld and redeploy.

Comment: In addition, without knowing where the file is packaged, we'll just be guessing.

Comment: So, where does prop.properties end up in the WAR file? Do you know how Struts attempts to load that file (likely using ClassLoader.getResource)?